# How can I align my NavBar items to the right with Boostrap v5.2?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is for a course project.

I want the brand to stay left-aligned, but the other items to align to the right.

I can do it when there's no toggler, using justify-content-end
But with a toggler, nothing works.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `class=me-auto` in the ul tag with `class=ms-auto`